# How to stop repetitions in rules in prolog

Tags: prolog

In my prolog rule

```
marriedcouple(X,Y) :-
    parent( (X,Z), bornin(_) ),
    parent( (Y,Z), bornin(_) ),
    female(X),
    male(Y)
    ;
    male(X),
    female(Y),
    different(X,Y).
```

when a parent has two kids, the couple shows twice. How can we prevent this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you've got `female/1` & `male/1` predicates the predicate becomes quite simple.

```
marriedcouple(X,Y) :-
    parent( (X,Z), bornin(_) ),
    parent( (Y,Z), bornin(_) ),
    female(X),
    male(Y).
```

However, if you want to see if X and Y are not the same use the `(\==)/2` operator for "not identical" or `(\=)/2` for "not unifiable".

---

> Pradeep, based on your comment below, here is a more complete solution.

In order to prevent the same answer coming back twice there's a number of choices. We can build a list of solutions and only add a newly found solution if it isn't already in the list. Or use an approach that incorporates state using the `assert/1` predicate.

I've chosen the latter.

```
?- solve.

solve :-
    marriedcouple(Dad, Mum),
    not( found( marriedcouple(Dad, Mum) ) ),
    assert( found( marriedcouple(Dad, Mum) ) ),
    write( [Dad, Mum] ),
    nl,
    fail.

marriedcouple(Dad, Mum) :-
    parent(Dad, Child),
    parent(Mum, Child),
    male(Dad),
    female(Mum).

male(aaron).
male(adam).

female(betty).
female(eve).

parent(aaron, callum).
parent(aaron, david).
parent(adam, abel).
parent(adam, cain).
parent(betty, callum).
parent(betty, david).
parent(eve, abel).
parent(eve, cain).
```

When I run this I get the following:

```
[aaron,betty];
[adam,eve];
No.
```

Be careful using `assert/1` predicates as you may introduce unwanted side-effects into your programs. You may need to do appropriate `retract/1` calls too.

Comment: Oh, and you had a semi-colon in your original predicate. That is likely to be a mistake. Cheers.

Comment: Semicolon is there to check whether X,Y is male or female. so its not the issue. 

from my problem the result i get is 

X=tom
Y=ann
X=tom
Y=ann
X=jack
Y=jane

i get two result because in that family they have two children. this is i want to stop. please can soemone tell me how to do it

Comment: The semi-colon will only apply to the male(Y) & male(X) predicates. It is equivalent to ",female(X), ( male(Y);male(X) ) ,female(Y)," and not ", ( female(X),male(Y) ) ; ( male(X),female(Y) ) ," which is what I think you meant.

Comment: @Kaarel - Thanks. I can never remember which way it goes. Might have to blame Windows vs Unix path separators. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just an theoretical solution through double-not:

```
marriedcouple(Dad, Mum) :-
    male(Dad), female(Mum),
    not(notMarriedcouple(Dad,Mum)).

notMarriedcouple(Dad, Mum) :-
    male(Dad), female(Mum),
    not((parent(Dad, Child), parent(Mum, Child))).
```

Comment: BTW, there is some systems (XSB) that supports tabulation ":-table marriedcouple/2."

Comment: This works in Prolog because `not/1` do not't have alternatives (not is usually defined through cut `not(G):-G,!,fail. not(G).`). In XSB works direct rule, because "tabulated" rules does caching of successfull goals thus no bagcktracing with same Goal.