# How to avoid repetition in prolog

Tags: prolog

I get several results with the same outputs.

I want to get `jack,jane` only one time, but I get it two times.

How can I avoid this? I tried `setof` but I couldn't get it done. Please can someone help me on this?

Comment: Probably your algorithms just creates the result two times. Without seeing the source code it is hard to say why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is duplicated in ["How to stop repetitions in rules in prolog"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460018/how-to-stop-repetitions-in-rules-in-prolog).

An answer is to do something like this:

```
solve :-
    marriedcouple(Dad, Mum),
    not(found(marriedcouple(Dad, Mum))),
    assert(found(marriedcouple(Dad, Mum))),
    write([Dad, Mum]),
    nl,
    fail.
```

Read the [full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460018/how-to-stop-repetitions-in-rules-in-prolog/2460634#2460634) for more detail.

Comment: i tried that solution but its not working. i really dont know why. it says those undefined

Comment: @Pradeep - what did you try and what "those" are undefined?